# Hardhat deploy contract Error: missing argument: in Contract constructor

Tags: hardhat

I'm trying to deploy my contract in my Hardhat project but I'm receiving this error: `missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)`

Help on solving this error would be greatly appreciated.

deploy.js

```
const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('Token')
  const tokenContract = await Token.deploy();
  const Loan = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('Loan')
  const loanContract = await Loan.deploy();
  await tokenContract.passMinterRole(loanContract.address);
  await loanContract(tokenContract.address);
```

Comment: either your token or loan contract is expecting an constructor argument, look at the constructors in the .sol files